# GitHub Action with MacOS-latest : Process completed with exit code 1 : with grep and curl command

Tags: bash, macos, grep, github-actions, github-for-mac

### Introduction

Currently, I'm writing a customized GitHub workflow inside it I use a curl and grep command.
[GitHub repo](https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Hiden-dependancy-updater)

#### action.yml

```yaml
    - name: get new tag
      id: get_new_tag
      shell: bash
      run: |
        temp_result=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/${{inputs.github_repository}}/tags | grep -h "name" | grep -h "${{inputs.selector}}" |  head -1 | grep -ho "${{inputs.regex}}")
        echo "new-tag=${temp_result}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

*Full code [here](https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Hiden-dependancy-updater/blob/b8a657c5e948bbe8f2bdb5e0e346ecd8df74729e/action.yml)*

#### test for action.yml

```yaml
        uses: ./
        with:
          files: tests/test1.txt tests/test2.txt
          github_repository: MathieuSoysal/file-updater-for-release
          prefix: MathieuSoysal/file-updater-for-release@
```

*Full code are is [here](https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Hiden-dependancy-updater/blob/b8a657c5e948bbe8f2bdb5e0e346ecd8df74729e/.github/workflows/test-action-final.yml#L38-L42)*

### Problem

I don't understand why but my GitHub Actions don't work with MacOS.

#### The given error:

```
  temp_result=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/MathieuSoysal/file-updater-for-release/tags | grep -h "name" | grep -h "" |  head -1 | grep -ho "v\?[0-9.]*")
  echo "new-tag=${temp_result}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  shell: /bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

*Full log error is [here](https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Hiden-dependancy-updater/actions/runs/4179382161/jobs/7239286813)*

#### Question

Does someone know how we can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can simply use the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command line utility for this which is already installed and available on the GitHub runners. See the [preinstalled software](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software).

```bash
$ export URL='https://api.github.com/repos/MathieuSoysal/file-updater-for-release/tags'
$ curl -s $URL | jq -r .[0].name
v1.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from this command `grep -h ""`, this command is not supported on MacOS.

The empty string is not supported, the solution is to add something inside it.